# JS-Ember: Cannot have my 'class' level observer notified

Tags: ember.js

I have the following case:

```
    ...
    SN.BaseService = Ember.Object.extend({

        action : null,

        send: function(action) {
            this.set('action', action);
        }
    });
    ...
    SN.userService = SN.BaseService.create({

        login: function() {
              if (some_condition) {
                  this.send("onSuccessfulLogin");
              } else {
                  this.send("onFailedLogin");
              }
        }

    });

    ...

    SN.BaseService.reopen({
          onAction: function() {
              doSomething();
          }.observes('action')
    });

    SN.BaseService.reopen({
          actionChanged: Ember.observer(function() {
              doSomething();
          }, 'action')
    });
```

My observers (regrdless of the way I set them up - both shown here) never get called i.e. doSomething() is never called.

Observers at object level work fine. It is only when I try to have them at 'class' level.
Feedback is very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're reopening a class after instanciate the object.
It looks like reopening the class does not update each instances.

If I'm not wrong, you can :

- Reopening the class before instanciating the userService ( see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTc2k/) )

  ```
  App.BaseService.reopen({
    onAction: function() {
       this.doSomething();
    }.observes('action')
  });

  App.BaseService.reopen({
    actionChanged: Ember.observer(function() {
       this.doSomething();
    }, 'action')
  });
  ```
- Reopening the userService directly ( see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rJ9u/) ).

  ```
  App.userService.reopen({
    onAction: function() {
      this.doSomething();
    }.observes('action')
  });

  App.userService.reopen({
    actionChanged: Ember.observer(function() {
      this.doSomething();
    }, 'action')
  });
  ```

There could be some better solutions but I do not know them.

Comment: Thanks for the information! In my case I need to reopen the class after instantiating objects. The solution is not applicable in my scenario but I will mark the reply as an "Answer" because it explains what the current behavior of Ember is. In case a better alternative pops up please share it. Thanks again